# Is it possible to set cache in one application and use it in another application?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to set cache in one application and use it in another application ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is Yes.  Regardless of the language you are using you can use a product such as MemCached (linux/unix), MemCached Win32 (windows), Velocity (Microsoft) in which such products are used for caching farms.

A caching farm is similar to a web farm in that it is a high availability and easily scalable solution...for caching.  In this case the cache is totally separate from the application itself.  So as long as you have a naming structure for your keys (assigned to the objects in the cache) you could technically span the cached content across not only applications but different platforms, languages, technologies, etc.

See more information regarding this here: [System.Web.Caching vs. Enterprise Library Caching Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870/system-web-caching-vs-enterprise-library-caching-block/984076#984076)

Answer (score 0):

You should really be much more specific in your questions. I have to assume you're talking about ASP.NET and the Cache property, but it's only a guess, since you didn't give any clue about what you're looking for (except that you said C#).

No, the Cache property is per-application.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your caching functionality in one application and make it available through .Net Remoting.

Then access it from your other application. Remember that all your objects you want to cache this way will have to be serializable. (you probably have to serialize/deserialize it on your end. not the cache app end)