# How do you work with data caching in you .net web application?

Tags: .net, caching

I'm currently looking how to work with caching on my web application I'm buildning.
I have an ormapper (nhibernate, not using second level cache), and I have built a cache frame, built on System.Web cache, that I pass in the objects.

My question is. Are there open source cache frameworks someone can recomend? 
Is their anything to gain form using the built in cache in the ormapper (like the second level cache in nhibernate)?

What is a good practice here?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870/system-web-caching-vs-enterprise-library-caching-block

Comment: Not looking for distributed caching. More in-depth of the technical solution of how to work with the cache.

Comment: There's plenty of general caching info in there (esp Andrew Siemer's answer).  I don't think you are going to find any decent open source caching frameworks that don't handle distributed scenarios - what would be the point? You might as well just stick with the web.cache in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If NHibernate has caching abilities than it would probably be a good idea to use this

Comment: Is it? I feel like I lack control over how the cache is used. It feels  like I need NHProf to check that I'm not doing it wrong.

Comment: What I'm say is what't the argument for going that way? Why is it a good idea?

Comment: Well, it gives you a complete integrated solution in one package. NHibernate is used by a lot of projects and there is lots of support available for it.

Disclaimer: I haven't used NHibernate myself (Still hoping to find the time to learn it) :-)